# Type Mismatch on the portion of the code that is between my asterisks

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am trying to run this code and am getting error type 13, mistmach error on the portion of the code that is highlighted (*). I am unsure why this error is occurring. I have tried defining the variables as both variant or integer and this does not work.

```
Sub Send_Email()

Dim outApp As Object
Dim outMail As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Body As String, Rng As Range

Dim ccEmailList As String
Dim i As Variant
Dim toEmailList As String
Dim j As Variant
Dim r As Variant

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)

Body = "Good afternoon, <br><br>Please find below the details of today's activity for your NCIB: <br><br> You bought: <b>" & Range("C7").Text & Range("D7") & Range("E7") & "$" & Range("F7") & _
        "</b><br>Settlement Date: <b>" & Range("C8").Text & "</b><br>Daily VWAP: <b>" & Range("C9").Text & "</b><br>Commission: <b>$" & Range("C10") & _
        "</b><br>Net CAD Amount: <b>" & Range("C11").Text & "</b><br><br>Thanks,"

Worksheets("Issuer data").Activate
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ccEmailList = ""
i = 23
r = Range("A1").Value
    
**'Loop to create the cc emailing list
Do While ws.Cells(i, r) <> ""
    ccEmailList = ccEmailList & ws.Cells(i, r) & ";"
    i = i + 1
Loop**

toEmailList = ""
j = 8
'Loop to create the to emailing list
Do While ws.Cells(j, r) <> ""
    toEmailList = toEmailList & ws.Cells(j, r) & ";"
    j = j + 1
Loop

Worksheets("Email generator").Activate

outMail.Display
outMail.To = toEmailList
outMail.CC = ccEmailList
outMail.BCC = ""
outMail.Subject = Cells(4, 2)
outMail.htmlbody = Body
   

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values of `i` and `r` when you get the error? (click debug to check them)

Comment: The values of i is set to 23 and r is set as the to 17 (from a formula in cell A1)

Comment: Then what is the value of `ws.Cells(i, r)` when it errors?

Comment: Note: You are sometimes qualifying your ranges and sometimes not, so you could be getting confused about which sheet is active at the time. It is much better to not use `ActiveSheet` and qualify the ranges with a specific sheet instead.

Comment: Try qualifying both instances of ws.Cells(i, r) with .Value i.e. ws.Cells(i, r).Value